# How can I establish the link between relational records in belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to create a simple belongs_to association between **User** and **CriminalRecord**. A user has only one record and a record belongs to a user. So far I have the following in the corresponding files.

*model > user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

*models > criminal_record.rb*

```
class CriminalRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*db > migrate > 20150902003211_create_criminal_records*

```
class CreateCriminalRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :criminal_records do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.murderer :boolean
      t.thief :boolean

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I am able to create a record for User and a record for CriminalRecord. However, I am unable to accomplish something like this even though I have user_id set to the user's id in the criminal record instance.

```
User.last.criminal_records
```

Or for that matter I am unable to do any of the following

```
john = User.last

john.criminal_record.create(murderer:false, thief: true)
# or
record = CriminalRecord.create(murderer:false, thief: true)
john << record
```

I get NoMethodError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `has_one` association in your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :criminal_record
end
```

And, if you already have `belongs_to :user` in your `CriminalRecord` Model and `user_id` column in your `criminal_records` table, then you are all set.

Then you will be able to do:

```
john = User.last
john.criminal_record
```

This is a very simple use case of Active Record Association. I highly recommend you to read the [Official Documentation for Active Record Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to know about the available association types and hoe they can be used in Rails application following the proper convention.